# User Agent is not accessible in Internet Explorer 8 using ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, internet-explorer-8, flash-builder, user-agent, externalinterface

I am using the code below to find the User Agent using ActionScript 3:

```
var userAgent:String = ExternalInterface.call("navigator.userAgent.toString");
```

The code is working in Firefox 13, Google Chrome & Opera, but the User Agent value as null in IE8.

Is there any code snippet that will work here or any other way to implement this?

Comment: What's your javascript to receive the ExternalInterface code?

Comment: Probably here is probably on the JS side

Answer (score 0):

`toString` is unnecessary, since userAgent is a string property. Use this syntax instead:

```
var userAgent:String = ExternalInterface.call("function(){return navigator.userAgent}")
```