# Detecting “Tablet/Touch Mode” in Edge using JavaScript on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, feature-detection, device-detection, forward-compatibility

This question was asked before, but the answers are not exactly what I need.

I need to distinguish in Microsoft Edge if it's a tablet or not (Desktop).

1) The following thread:
[Can you detect "Tablet Mode" in Edge and IE11 using JavaScript on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493093/)

worked indeed, but I'm afraid that in the next version Microsoft will change the behavior.

How can I be sure that they won't?

Answers with `if condition of window.PointerEvent` do not work at all, since it's defined in Desktop.

I can't use CSS Media Queries Interaction media features as suggested here:
[Is there any way to detect if user has launched microsoft edge tablet or desktop browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31780562/)

Comment: "It worked indeed, but I'm afraid that in the next version Microsoft will change the behavior. how can I be sure that they won't?" You can never be sure. But given that Windows 10 for PCs has just been out for barely a few months, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish this?

Comment: Patrick - For instance with desktop you can do hover with mouse and then you can see tooltip, In tablet the behavior is different (no hover), I have a lot of examples of different behaviors but I think it's not the scope here.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but you could start out by assuming that the user has a mouse, and when you detect a "pointerup" event, then switch the behavior to a more touch-friendly mode.

Comment: I don't know about win10 and edge, but from experience it is impossible to differentiate a MS Surface with IE 11 from a Laptop with IE 11 equipped with a touch screen. This was a deliberate decision Microsoft made when they first developed this. Not sure if they moved away from this with Edge and Win10

Answer (score 0):

Here are the hardware specific differences in the Edge browser capabilities:

> The only differences are due to certain device-specific qualities – for example, codec support may be different on phones due to missing hardware acceleration, and Flash is not supported on Windows 10 Mobile. Because Windows 10 Mobile has a different background model, RTC (Real-Time Communications) APIs are also currently not supported. Finally, Windows 10 Mobile does not support Flash in order to provide a modern, touch-focused, and power-efficient experience appropriate for a mobile device. Because of this, Flash is not supported in Microsoft Edge in Continuum.

To detect RTC capabilities, use the following code:

```
if (RTCRtpCapabilities)
  {
  initRTC();
  }
function initRTC()
  {
  var recvAudioCaps = RTCRtpReceiver.getCapabilities("audio"); 
  var recvVideoCaps = RTCRtpReceiver.getCapabilities("video"); 
  var sendAudioCaps = RTCRtpSender.getCapabilities("audio");
  var sendVideoCaps = RTCRtpSender.getCapabilities("video"); 
  }
```

Embedding a Flash movie which uses an [ExternalInterface call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310227/1113772) would be the easiest way to detect Flash.

The properties of the `navigator` object should be able to distinguish tablet from phone. For example:

```
navigator.cpuClass
```

should return `x86` for Surface devices, but `other` for phones.

Also, the user agent changes when casting a phone display to a TV. It goes from:

- Microsoft Edge UA (Mobile)

  ```
  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 6.0.1; Microsoft; <Device>) AppleWebKit/<Rev (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<Rev> Mobile Safari/<Rev> Edge/<Rev>
  ```

to:

- Microsoft Edge UA (Continuum)

  ```
  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; ARM) AppleWebKit/<Rev> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<Rev> Safari/<Rev> Edge/<Rev>
  ```

compared to the desktop:

- Microsoft Edge UA (Desktop)

  ```
  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/<Rev> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<Rev> Safari/<Rev> Edge/<Rev>
  ```

**References**

- [Microsoft Edge and Continuum: Your desktop browser on Mobile](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/08/24/microsoft-edge-continuum/)
- [Microsoft Edge Dev Guide: Object RTC API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/dev-guide/realtime-communication/object-rtc-api/)
- [ORTC Specification: dictionary RTCRtpCapabilities](http://draft.ortc.org/#rtcrtpcapabilities)
- [Flash Player guidance for Internet Explorer 11 and Microsoft Edge](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2015/10/flash-player-guidance-for-internet-explorer-11-and-microsoft-edge.html)
- [Minimum Hardware Requirements: Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn915086)
- [Continuum for Phones FAQ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/12366/windows-10-mobile-continuum-for-phones-faq)
- [clientInformation object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770694.aspx)
- [Device Fingerprint Help](http://noc.to/#!Help)
- [Security Error when trying to call ActionScript function from JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307335/1113772)
- [The Windows 10 Browser Conundrum](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjacks/2016/06/21/the-windows-10-browser-conundrum/)
- [how to tell if android user came from home screen app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560799/how-to-tell-if-android-user-came-from-home-screen-app)
- [Configuring Web Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)